# Roslyn: How to replace an IdentifierName with an Expression

Tags: c#, roslyn

I am trying to use a Roslyn rewriter but I am not being able to replace an IdentifierName by an Expression.

From what I understood when doing a visitor to do such replacement they need to match in type. Is there any workaround to do this substitution ignoring the type?

```
public class NameRewriter : CSharpSyntaxRewriter
{
   private readonly ExpressionSyntax newExpr;

   public NameRewriter(ExpressionSyntax newExpr) {
          this.newExpr = newExpr;
   }

  public override SyntaxNode VisitIdentifierName(IdentifierNameSyntax node) {
          return node.ReplaceNode(node, newExpr);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return type of `ReplaceNode()` is the same as its `this` parameter, so to make sure `ReplaceNode()` does not throw, cast it to `SyntaxNode`:

```
return ((SyntaxNode)node).ReplaceNode(node, newExpr);
```

Though in your case, `ReplaceNode()` is not necessary at all, it's enough to just return the new expression:

```
return newExpr;
```

Both of the above options will work only when the `IdentifierNameSyntax` can actually be replaced with the given expression. For example replacing all `IdentfierName`s in `foo();` will work with pretty much any expression, e.g. using `bar()` results in `bar()();`. But doing the same for `var x = foo();` won't work, because `bar() x = bar()();` is not syntactically valid.

On the other hand, using something like `bar` should work anytime, since it's another `IdentifierName`.

Also, doing this can leave you with missing required whitespace, for example using `bar` on `var x = foo();` results in valid tree, but one with invalid textual representation: `barx = bar();`. So don't forget to format the resulting tree afterwards.